# Samsung Galaxy Tab 7" 2gb Android upgrade is it posable

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I have a sch-i800 galaxy tab and I wouldlike to up grade the programing so I can use some of the newer programs out there is this posible?

hardware version i800.0.4

firmware v 2.3.5

baseband v S:i800.0.4v.ei04

kernal v 2.6.35.7

Build # sch-i800.mc2

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/P1c_Info

get some cyanogenmod running on it. Follow the link above

The latest stable version is linked below.

http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?type=stable&device=p1c